# How do I create an <iframe> tag when it is hover sets an achor?

Tags: html, css

Iframe doesn't let me click the anchor tag when im hovering .most_visited, Is there any way to solve it? I tried with rerversing z-index but iframe stays on the top and cant click on it.

```
<div class="most_visited">
                        <a href="../../random/index.html">
                            <div class="backgroun_iamge_pmv"></div>
                            <iframe class="cv_embebed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                        </a>
</div>
```

```
.cv_embebed{
  align-self: center;
  width: 20.1em;
  height: 25em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.most_visited:hover > a{
z-index:1;
}

.most_visited:hover > a > .backgroun_iamge_pmv{
  background: linear-gradient(black, grey);
  width: 20.1em;
  height: 25em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.most_visited:hover > a > .cv_embebed{
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateY(-25em);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Including an `<iframe>` is like including an outside html page. This outside html is in control of its content, not your `<a>`. Unless you use `a { padding: .... }` and create some space around the `<iframe>` your user can click or add clickable content to your `<a>`. You cannot control the `<iframe>` content from the calling main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your `<a>` element *after* the `<iframe>` in your HTML and absolutely position it over the top.

```css
.most_visited {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.most_visited:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(black, grey);
}

.cv_embebed {
  width: 20em;
  height: 15em;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: block;
}

.anchor_link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="most_visited">
    <iframe class="cv_embebed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <a class="anchor_link" href="https://google.com" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```